# Multiple images upload

Tags: django

I was using this code form simple model (without any relations). But I've problem with two models, `Gallery` and `GalleryImage`

https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)


class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='image_in_gallery')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/%Y/%m/%d')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What should `forms.py` in this case seems?